# How to use exchangeArgsConfigurer in rabbitmq in Camel?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel, rabbitmq-exchange

I am using alternate exchange in the RabbitMQ. And coding language in Java Camel framework.

I wanted to know who to use the exchangeArgsConfigurer in the RabbitMQ URL. As we don't have the proper documentation on camel website. (http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Official Camel RabbitMQ page is outdated. You can refer the updated document [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/docs/rabbitmq-component.adoc)

exchangeArgsConfigurer is deprecated, now we can simply use arg.queue or arg.exchange or arg.binding in rabbitMQ URI to add arguments.

Eg:
rabbitmq://exz.router.main?exchangeType=headers&skipQueueDeclare=true&autoDelete=false&arg.exchange.alternate-exchange=exz.router.ae&autoAck=false

http://localhost:5672/exchange/queueargs=arg.queue.x-message-ttl=5000